# Django how to use generic view with UUID instead of PK

Tags: django

I'm trying to access a url that's like

127.0.0.1:8000/posti/qNwEXBxXQdGI4KlQfoHWOA

However I can't resolve that smalluuid.

This is the error:

> NoReverseMatch at /posti/ Reverse for 'detail' with arguments
>   '(SmallUUID('qNwEXBxXQdGI4KlQfoHWOA'),)' not found. 1 pattern(s)
>   tried: ['posti/(?P[0-9a-fA-F-]+)/$']

Django has issues trying to resolve it in another view that has a string like this:

```
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import url


app_name = 'posti'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[0-9a-fA-F-]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

My DetailView is this one:

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'posti/detail.html'
    slug_field = 'uuid'



    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Excludes any questions that aren't published yet.
        """
        return Post.objects.all()
```

I tried rewriting get_object but it didn't do anything. I don't understand if the regex is wrong or if my view has something wrong.

EDIT:

My template on index raised the error above and it had the following code:

```
{% if posti_list != null %}
    <ul>
    {% for post in posti_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'posti:detail' post.uuid %}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No posts are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

I added `slug_url_kwarg = 'uuid'` to the DetailView class and now it works BUT now I have a

> AttributeError at /posti/qNwEXBxXQdGI4KlQfoHWOA/ Generic detail view
>   DetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug.

When I try to access the specific post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I added `slug_url_kwarg = 'uuid'` to the DetailView class and now it works BUT now I have a
>
> > AttributeError at /posti/qNwEXBxXQdGI4KlQfoHWOA/ Generic detail view DetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug.

`slug_url_kwarg` must match your url regex group name (`slug` in your case, which is default value for `slug_url_kwarg`), so you shouldn't have changed it

For details look at the piece of Django source code here - https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/detail.py#L8

Comment: RIght. I read an example where it said "slug" and i thought it was supposed to be called that way.